# Efficient way to display images(serve images) in MEAN stack application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I am developing a MEAN stack application and i want to display the images with some responses.
Exact Requirement: There is search box , when user enter the name of the image , server should respond with that image and browser display that image.
I have maximum of 70 images with size 30kb maximum.
Should I store these inside the mongoDB and for every request node server hit the  mongodb and serve that image in the response or I serve it with Angular.js?
Please recommend the efficient way to do that.

Comment: serve it with Angular.js? How ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can setup a folder for static content (CSS, images, etc) do it in your expess.js configuration probably you'll find something like this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve('./public')));
app.use('/images',express.static(path.resolve('youPathToStaticimages')));
```

Then create a collection with the image metadata, like file name, size, uploaded date, friendly name and maybe tags or any other field that you can query.

Then use an endpoint / [$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource) combination and retrieve the data and display the images in the client with a simple HTML image tag (IMG) and use [ng-src](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc), probably within a ngRepeat.

For me that could be the easiest way to do it, also you can set some sort of cache policy to your image folder in apache or ngnix.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a little over 2mb of data which can be easily cached.  Transferring from the database to the web server or retrieving from disk is extra work.  Load all the images into your node thread and when the keyword comes through send the cached image.